# how to use isomap on face images by R

Tags: r

i use isomap function in library（RDRToolbox）.my data are 210 tiff face images.it includes 30 people and every people have 7 pics.i want to use isomap to reduce dimension and then knn class them.but auc is very low.i want to know why
please help me .i am a rookie in r.
thank you

this is my code：
filename1=dir("E:/train/")
library(tiff)

```
for(i in 1:length(filename1)){
```

assign(paste("t",i,sep=""),readTIFF(filename1[i]))
}

```
newmatrix1<-c()  

for(i in 1:length(filename1)){
name<-paste("t",i,sep = "")
temp<-as.numeric(get(name))
newmatrix1<-rbind(newmatrix1,temp)
```

}

```
library(RDRToolbox)
data1=newmatrix1
a1=Isomap(data1,dims =2, 7，mod = FALSE,plotResiduals = FALSE, verbose = TRUE)
```

and it produces a warning message.it says it produces Nans.what is that？how to solve it.why it can produce？

then i choose everyone 1-5 pics as traindata and 6-7 as testdata.i use knn and get a bad outcome.it gets all wrong class

please help me.need help thank you！！！